# Singletop activity doesn't resume on Back Button press

Tags: java, android, back

I have an activity, let's call it activity A, which defined in the manifest as "launchmode:singleTop",
and an activity B whose parent is activity A(defined in the manifest).
But for some reason, when I click the back button on activity B, it doesn't resume activity A but creates it, I know this because I've wrote a log line in the onCreate function in activity A which is called when pressing on the back button in B.
What could be the reason for that? It worked for me before but suddenly this problem started.

A is the activity GroupStandingsActivity and B is AddStandingsActivity.

The manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.amigo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/GreenTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MatchResultsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.TeamAssignmentActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.GroupStandingsActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.AddPlayerActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.AddStandingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.AddStandingsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.GroupStandingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.AddEditGroupActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.GroupListActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.GroupListActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.GroupStandingsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.GroupListActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code that starts AddStandingActivity:
There is a menu button that starts the AddStandingsActivity

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_standings_menu:
                addPlayer();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void addPlayer() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GroupStandingsActivity.this, AddStandingsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AddStandingsActivity.EXTRA_GROUP_ID, groupID);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_STANDINGS_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your manifest? Also provide the code that start your activity B.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев Hi I edited the question with the manifest and the code that starts B.

Comment: Is this happens on every Activity A-->Activity B-->Activity A navigation chain, or only sometimes?

Comment: @НиколайГольцев every chain like this.

Comment: Did you change something in Developer options? There is setting called "Don't keep activities", it must be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

When your activity A goes into background, the system may destroy it to free up memory. When the user closes your activity B, the system has to create activity A again, and onCreate will be called with non-null savedInstanceState parameter.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help.
That's why I set it as a singleTop launch mode, so that it won't recreate it, how can I fix it?

Comment: Nothing can guarantee that your activity will not be destroyed when it goes into background. This is how Android works. You should be ready for this scenario.

Comment: singleTop means that if the activity exists in the task, it will be reordered to front instead of being created. It has nothing to do with the issue you are facing. The launch mode is irrelevant here.